# React - How to use cloneElement so it preserves context

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React's undocumented context feature, [per this article](https://blog.jscrambler.com/react-js-communication-between-components-with-contexts/). I noticed there's a caveat, which is that this context feature only works if you explicitly invoke a component:

```
render() {
  return <div><SomeComponent /></div>
}
```

If you clone the item, though, context is not passed down:

```
render() {
  return <div>{React.cloneElement(this.props.content)}</div>
}
```

Is this a bug? Or is there some way to make this work that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha. Apparently before 0.14, you need to use `React.addons.cloneWithProps` to preserve context. And at 0.14 and up, `React.cloneElement` should do the job.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4008